# Javafx TilePane PrefColumns

Tags: javafx

I am having problems producing the correct number of columns in a `TilePane` row.

I'm trying just to have ten columns per row. I know I'm missing the obvious. So, I need another pair of eyes.

The `setPrefColumns` method does not appear to work the way I have it coded.

```java
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Main extends Application {
    TilePane tp = new TilePane();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        try {
            primaryStage.setResizable(false);  
            tp.setPrefColumns(10);
            setTP();    

            Scene scene = new Scene(tp,800,600);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setTP() {           
        tp.setVisible(true);

        int[] numbers = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

        for(int row=0; row<11; row++) {

            for (int i: numbers ) {

                Text t = new Text(String.valueOf(i));

                HBox hbox = new HBox();
                hbox.getChildren().add(t);

                hbox.setStyle("-fx-border-color: red;");
                tp.getChildren().add(hbox);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example TilePane behaves as specified:

> Note that prefColumns/prefRows is used only for calculating the preferred size and may not reflect the actual number of rows or columns, which may change as the tilepane is resized and the tiles are wrapped at its actual boundaries.

As root of the scene it is sized to fill the complete width (800 in your context):

```
Scene scene = new Scene(tp,800,600);
```

To make it wrap on its prefColumns, you need to add it to a layout that respects its content's prefWidth, f.i. a HBox:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new HBox(tp),800,600);
```